# unexpected conversion <list> of bytes to <bytes> in python

Tags: python, list, types, byte

I can't figure out how to easy feed list of bytes to 'bytes' type. Although I make list be feeded by "for" loop. And that list suddenly transformed to 'bytes' class too.
my code below:

```
    bit0=bytearray()
    bit=[int(0).to_bytes(length=input.sample_width, byteorder='big', signed=True)
         [1::-1] for y in [z*input.channels for z in range(input.channels)]]
    print(type(bit),bit)
    for bit in bit:
        bit0+=bit  
    print(type(bit),bit)
```

<class 'list'> [b'\x00\x00']
<class 'bytes'> b'\x00\x00'

I could expect <class 'bytes'> b'\x00' because each bit in bit have '\x00'
I pretty frustrated by python for that because that is not my cap of tea.

my python is "Python 3.8.18"

```
for bit in bit:
    bit0+=bit
```

that loop should have any way to transform type of "bit" variable.

Comment: `for bit in bit` The original `bit` list is lost because you've overwritten it with a loop variable of the same name.  Did you intend to use the same names here?

Answer (score 0):

In your loop:

```
for bit in bit:
    bit0 += bit
```

You're iterating over bit which is initially a list of byte objects. However, within the loop, you're reusing the name bit as the loop variable. So, in each iteration, bit is no longer referencing the list, but rather each individual byte object in that list.

When you print type(bit) after the loop, it indeed shows <class 'bytes'> because bit is now referencing the bytes object, not the list.

To fix this, you should use a different variable name in the loop:

```
for b in bit:
    bit0 += b
```

This way, you're iterating over the list bit and appending each byte object b to bit0, without changing the reference of bit itself.

Here's the corrected code:

```
bit0 = bytearray()
bit = [int(0).to_bytes(length=input.sample_width, byteorder='big', signed=True)[1::-1] 
       for y in [z*input.channels for z in range(input.channels)]]
print(type(bit), bit)
for b in bit:
    bit0 += b
print(type(bit), bit)
```